# How to return additional values from flatMap in RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need to return an additional value other than Observable, `key` string from `flatMap` from below setup:

```
this.subscribeInit = this.tradingService.getInProgress()
.pipe(flatMap((s) => {
    this.keys = s.map((tdi) => tdi.key);
    return this.keys;
}),
flatMap((key) =>{
    var res = this.tradingService.getTradingData(key);//returns `Observable<any>`
    return res;
}))
.subscribe(res => {
    console.log('Key is : ' + res.key);
}, 
undefined,
() => this.onComplete());
```

Something like:

```
flatMap((key) =>{
    var res = this.tradingService.getTradingData(key);
    return {res,key};
}))
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use map ...

```
flatMap((key) =>{
    return this.tradingService.getTradingData(key).pipe(map((res) => {
        return {res,key};
    }));
}))
```

ps: i am a bit confused: isnt flatMap deprecated and replaced my mergeMap, switchMap, ... ?

edit: apparently the problem was caused by using flatMap instead of mergeMap.

Comment: Doesn't work _Argument of type '(key: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'_.

Comment: what is the returntype of getTradingData?

Comment: It returns `Observable<any>`

Comment: You are right as mentioned [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html), " flatMap is an alias for mergeMap!" and once I changed from `flatMap` to `mergeMap`. It worked. Thanks a ton! You might want to change ur answer to use `mergeMap`.

Comment: Do you still have the import statement for the flatMap? Could it be that you were importing it from the wrong location?

Comment: I used this import statement `import {flatMap, mergeMap , map} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Strange, that looks like the correct import location. I thought flatMap was renamed to mergeMap though, and i was not aware you can still import it.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructur object as function parameters

```
this.subscribeInit = this.tradingService.getInProgress()
    .pipe(flatMap((s) => {
            this.keys = s.map((tdi) => tdi.key);
            return this.keys;
        }),
        flatMap((key) =>{
            var res = this.tradingService.getTradingData(key);
            return {res,key}; // pack res and key into object
        }))
    .subscribe(({res,key}) => { // destructuring previously returned object
            console.log('Key is : ' + res[key]);
        },
        undefined,
        () => this.onComplete());
```

```js
const val1 = 'some val1', val2 = 'some val2';
Promise.resolve({val1, val2}).then(({val1, val2}) => {
 console.log(val1);
 console.log(val2);
});
```

Comment: Already tried this. Error: _Argument of type '(key: string) => { res: Observable<any>; key: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'_

Comment: Pls validate it doesn't work, as I mentioned I get the error as in my previous comment.

Comment: You need to turn off type check for this.