# combine two observables in nested observable in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to combine two observable and return new observable where second one is depends on value of first one.
here I'm expecting new object which is combination of few values of first one and few values of second one.

```
export interface EmpData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export const EMPDATA: EmpData = {
    id : 11, name : 'xyz'
};

 export interface EmpDetails {
  id: number;
  desiganation: string;
}

export const EMPDATAILS: EmpDetails = {
    id : 11, desiganation : 'manager'
};

  getEmpData(name: string): Observable<EmpData> {
   // search based on name and return object 
   // temporary returning some data
    return of(EMPDATA);
  }

  getEmpDetails(id: number): Observable<EmpDetails> {
  // search based on id and return object 
   // temporary returning some data
    return of(EMPDATAILS);
  }

  getEmploye(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getEmpData(name).pipe(
      flatMap((response) => {
        return this.getEmpDetails(response.id);
    );
  });

 this.getEmploye(xyz).subscribe(response =>
     // here I'm expecting response as below, i.e. combination of first and 
     //second observable
      //{ 
      //  id: 11,name:'XYZ', desiganation : 'manager'
      //}
```

Comment: You should use forkjoin and merge 2 array.

Comment: Check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51634405/4868839 using `flatMap`. you would just need `map` inside the `flatMap`.

Comment: yes, its working, thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
getEmploye(name: string): Observable<any> 
{
    return this.getEmpData(name).pipe(
      switchMap((response) => {
        return forkJoin(of(response),this.getEmpDetails(response.id);
    ),
    map(res=>{return {...res[0],...res[1]}}))
}
```

You get this.getEmpData. Then return a jorkJoin of the union of the response and this.getEmpDetails. Finally you map the result to get an uniqe object with the properties of both

NOTE: if you want to have separate the main and the detail data the last map can be like

```
map(res=>{return {...res[0],detail:res[1]}}))
```

Comment: yes, I need to merge the data here, instead of passing both res[0] and res[1] so my final output will be single object which will hold below data
{
  id:1,
  name:xyz,
  designation:manager
}

Comment: :gulps: I wrote return {...res[0],res[1]}, really is {...res[0],...res[1]} -yet corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Observable.forkJoin
```

Also in this file of best angular boilerplate project i can show you, how to use it:
[Link to usage in ngir project](https://github.com/mohammad-haji/ngir/blob/master/src/app/%40core/services/menu-loader.service.ts)

Hope it help.

Comment: Observable.forkJoin can be nested with others also

Comment: I read it about forkjoin and documentation says if you want to execute multiple request parallelly and combine the result in one then use forkjoin.

Comment: In my case, inner is depends on outer so inner get execute only when outer complete it.

Comment: got it, we can also use forkJoin as suggested above.